# How do I see that the function defined by $f(x)=x^{\alpha}$ if $x\in (0, 1]$ and $f(0)=0$ for every $\alpha$ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E=[0, 1]$. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Define $f$ on $E$ by $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
&x^{\alpha} \quad\;\text{if}\;x \in (0, 1]\\
&0 \quad\;\;\;\text{if}\;x = 0
\end{cases}$$
How do I prove $f$ is measurable on $E$?

Clearly $f$ isn't continuous on $E$ so I need something else.

The sets $f^{-1}((c, \infty)) = \{x \in E \mid f(x) > c\}$ for $c>0$ would probably need to be intervals but how do I check this? (It's simple enough to see that $f^{-1}(0)$ is measurable.) I'll probably need to check this for different cases of $\alpha$ too, I think.

Also, would this function be Riemann integrable? The reason I ask is that $f$ would be the pointwise limit of the sequence $$f_n=x^{\alpha} \chi_{[1/n, 1]}$$
so how would I go about evaluating the Lebesgue integrals $\int_{[0, 1]} f$ and $\int_{[0, 1]} f_n$ if these are not Riemann integrable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In measure theory, you can generally ignore what happens on sets of measure $0$. Because $g=f_{|(0,1]}$ is continuous, it is measurable. For any Borel set $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we have

$$f^{-1}(B)=\begin{cases}
g^{-1}(B), &\text{ if } 0\not\in B\\
g^{-1}(B)\cup\{0\}, &\text{ if } 0\in B
\end{cases}$$

which is a measurable set in any case.

As for its integral, note that

$$\int_{[0, 1]} f=\int_{(0, 1]} f$$

and try applying the monotone convergence theorem to the pointwise convergent sequence of functions you've constructed.